# Weird output from URL html source Swift

Tags: swift

Basically I'm trying to download the HTML source code of a `URL` object into a String...

I've followed step-by-step examples of how-to-do so on StackOverflow.

```
import Foundation

try! print(String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, encoding: .utf16))
```

This is a small sample of the output I'm getting:

```
楤瑨㨱〰╽䁭敤楡⁡汬笮杢ㅻ桥楧桴㨲㉰砻浡牧楮⵲楧桴㨮㕥活癥牴楣慬ⵡ汩杮㩴潰紣杢慲筦汯慴
```

When I was really just expecting some plain HTML output.

The only thing I could think that's causing this issue has to be related to Networking(such as the `DNS` servers being queried). But, just in case I'm asking it on here to get a review of the code.

Comment: how are you outputing it? a sample URL would be handy here to try and replicate

Comment: @Scriptable The `try! print()` line is doing both the outputting and includes the sample URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you want to encode the output to `UTF-16`, although removing it should work:

```
try! print(String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
```

That should return the `html` of the `URL`.

You can use an encoding, however, `UTF-16` is likely not correct in this circumstance.

```
try! print(String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!, encoding: .ascii))
```

`ASCII` would likely work.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: What about instead using `URLSession`, followed by reading the HTTPHeaders of the response, and you might get info about the encoding to use (usually, it's set to the correct one).